# How to check if the individual items in a tuple are not in list

Tags: python

I would like choose a random tuple from a list of tuples and add it to another list. But only if the single numbers in the tuples are not in the list already.
I tried with this but it failed:

```
from random import choice

MyList = []
T = [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(1,3)]

while len(MyList) <=4:
    p = choice(T)
    p1 = p[0]
    p2 = p[1]
    if p1,p2 not in MyList:
        MyList.append(p1,p2)
```

Comment: The objective is purposeless. Won't you just be making a copy of T?

Comment: You want to choose a random tuple from a list of tuples and add _the tuple_ to a new list if _the tuple_ isn't already there, or add _each item in the tuple's contents_ to a new list if _each item_ isn't already there?

Comment: @MalikBrahimi: not a copy, but a random reordering.

Comment: @user413734: `list.append()` only takes one argument. What is the purpose of your last line of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while len(myList) <= 4:
    p = choice(T)
    if not any(i in myList for i in p):
        myList.extend(p)

>>> myList
[1, 2, 5, 6, 3, 4]
```

So to check if multiple elements are in a list, you could use what I showed above

```
if not any(i in myList for i in p):
```

Comment: That's a good answer, but I don't understand the purpose of the program? Won't the new list be a copy of list T?

Comment: @MalikBrahimi No it won't. It will be a flattened subset of `T`.

Comment: Works ! Thanks. I have to wait 4 minutes to accept your answer :)

Comment: @user413734: please edit your question.  in the question, you state that you want to "choose a random tuple from a list of tuples and add *it* [the tuple] to another list."  based on your acceptance of this answer, it is clear that what you want is not to add the tuple, but the individual items within the tuple.

Comment: you should use a set for the checks. this works but has needlessly poor O complexity

Comment: @Cyber So why doesn't he use `random.shuffle` to do so?

Answer (score 0):

If the order is not important, you can use sets instead of list

```
from random import choice
from sets import Set

MyList = Set()
T = [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(1,3)]

while len(MyList) <=4:
    MyList.update(choice(T))

>>> MyList
Set([1, 2, 3, 5, 6])
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the single numbers of the tuple in a set when inserting, and check if the numbers of the tuple are in the set before inserting.

Comment: Why check for membership? Adding repeats doesn't affect a `set`.